# User unable to view TextChannel after I give it permission to do so

Tags: javascript, typescript, discord.js

I'm on discord.js@dev branch, version 13.0.0-dev.4206e35.1626350625

A channel has the following `permissionOverwrites`:

```js
[
    {
        id: <Guild>.id,
        deny: [
            'VIEW_CHANNEL',
        ],
        type: 'role',
    },
]
```

And then I'm doing:

```js
<GuildChannel>.permissionOverwrites.edit(<User>.id, {
    'SEND_MESSAGES': true,
    'VIEW_CHANNEL': true,
}, {
    type: 1,
})
```

I'm getting a "Missing Permissions" exception thrown by it but I have no idea what permission am I missing. I have `MANAGE_CHANNELS` already.

Comment: What version of discord.js are you using?

Comment: Is your bot's highest role higher than that of the target user?

Comment: @user15517071 Target user has no role except for `@everyone`, and my bot has its own special role which is created for every bot. @Lioness100 am on version 13.0.0-dev.4206e35.1626350625

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the `MANAGE_ROLES` permission. Apparently, you don't need it to set the channel permissions on creation but you need it to edit them.